Google Play Console - no account owner
At my Home tab of play.google.com/console, it says I need to verify my developer account by 31 Jan 2025. But then it says only the account owner can verify this developer account, and the Get started button is disabled.
I go to Users and permissions tab and there's only 1 user, me. As far as I know, there's no other email address that has access to this developer account (I transferred ownership from a previous email that's no longer accessible).
Various other places in the UI are also disabled because I'm not the account owner.
Is there a way to rectify this situation and make the 1 email address that has access to this Developer Account be the account owner for it?
